# Use babel's `main` key in global options

Tags: babel, document-classes, documentclass-writing, class-options

In one of my templates, I need to load `babel` in the `.cls` file, as some functionalities in the `.cls` file depend on babel. I would, however, like to keep the flexibility for the user to set whatever language he wants. Therefore, I thought about recommending to set the language options globally in the `\documentclass[<options>]{class}` macro. When using one language only, this works well, but there can be the need to define a main language and a secondary one. Babel has a built-in functionality to do this, it's the `main` keyword. So you could say `\usepackackage[ngerman, main=english]{babel}`. As I want to set the options globally, I tried `\documentclass[ngerman, main=english]{babel}`, which does not seem to work. Babel ignores the `main=english` and prints all the localized strings in German.

```tex
\documentclass[ngerman, main=english]{article}

\usepackage{babel}

\begin{document}
    \begin{abstract}
        Test
    \end{abstract}
\end{document}
```

> Zusammenfassung

If the `translations` package is loaded, and only `main=english` is given as a global option, the fallback translation is used, again showing, that babel ignores the `main=english` option if it is provided globally.

```tex
\documentclass[main=english]{article}

\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{translations}

\DeclareTranslationFallback{translate}{Fallback}
\DeclareTranslation{english}{translate}{English}
\DeclareTranslation{german}{translate}{German}

\begin{document}
    \GetTranslation{translate}
\end{document}
```

> Fallback

Why is the global option not passed to babel (or ignored by the latter) and how could I still define globally which language should be the main language of the document and which other languages should be loaded?

Comment: There is no need to use `main` to set the main language - the last language will be the main one. The key `main` should not be used except if for some reason the main language is not correctly set (typically when languages are set as both class and package options). In other words, write `\documentclass[ngerman, english]{article}`.